# Imposing a given constrain (f(x,y)>0) in a variational problem

Tags: calculus-of-variations, constraints

**My problem**

I am trying to solve a chemistry problem stating it as a constrained variational problem. I am learning this subject by myself and I have problems imposing a non-integral constrain.

One constrain is of the form:

$$ \int \int c_1 f(x,y) dx dy = C_1$$

The funcitional to be minimized is

$$ \int \int \left[ c_2 f(x,y) g(x,y) + c_3 f^2(x,y) \right] dx dy$$

where $g(x,y)$ is known and both integrals share the same integration limits. $C_1, c_1, c_2, c_3$ are also known constants. So up to this point I wrote as my lagrangian as

$$ L = c_2 f(x,y) g(x,y) + c_3 f^2(x,y) + \lambda f(x,y)$$

There is not explicit dependence of $L$ with derivatives of $f(x,y)$. The problem appears when I want to impose:

$$ f(x,y) \ge 0$$

I am not 100% sure about how to do it, and, if I did it right, I do not know how use take advantage of that constrain while solving the Euler-Lagrange equations.

**My efforts**

- I tried using a substitution $f(x,y)=u(x,y)^2$, but this leads me to the same solution than before.
- I made some tries with the [sign](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sign_function) function, replacing $f(x,y)$ in my constrain with $c_1 f(x,y)sign(f(x,y))$. I am not sure that this is right and also leads me to an Euler-Lagrange equation that I cannot solve using my knowledge in math. I also tried to approximate the $sign$ function  with similar results.
- I tried adding $-\lambda(x,y) f(x,y)$ to the Lagrangian, but I am not sure if that is correct. I see no difference with imposing $ 0 \ge f(x,y) $ instead. In any case, I added a new E-L equation to be satisfied in which $\lambda(x,y)$ plays the roll of $f(x,y)$, but it trivially leads me to $f(x,y)=0$, so I am doing something wrong.

**Question**

How to impose $ f(x,y) \ge 0$, and, if I did it right, how to solve the Euler-Lagrange equation?

Thank you

Comment: Can't you just solve it and pick the positive one?

Comment: @Botond, Thank you for your comment. I did so, but then I realized that I am discarding interesting cases. The integral constrain tries to reflect the conservation of matter. Negative values may have non sense.

Comment: Maybe an $f(x,y)-|f(x,y)|=0$ condition? I think in that case the additional term will be $\lambda(x,y)[f(x,y)-|f(x,y)|]$, but it's not 100%.

Comment: @Botond I do not know (I am new to this and I am not a mathematician). I think that the E-L eq. for lambda will give $f(x,y)=|f(x,y)|$, which is right, but I cannot see how to take advantage of this when using the E-L eq. for f(x,y).

Comment: Me neither - I'm just a physics student. But I think our teacher mentioned that in the case of these kind of constraints, we should do the same, but the lambda will be a function instead of a constant.

Comment: @Botond , That is why I considered a E-L eq. for  the $\lambda$ you proposed. Deriving the lagrangian with respect of $\lambda(x,y)$ I get $f(x,y)−|f(x,y)| =0$. That is what I tried to say in my previous comment. In fact, I get something like this for almost any case, so I suspect that something is wrong

Comment: I will try to ask someone about it.

Comment: @Botond, I really appreciate that :-)

Comment: Didn't you miss out something from the Lagrangian? It does not depend on $f'$ and $g'$, so without the last constrant, your Euler-Lagrange equations are $c_2 g(x,y)+2c_3 f(x,y)+\lambda=0$ and $c_2 f(x,y)=0$. So if the $c$'s are given, the solution is $f=0$ and $g=-\frac{\lambda}{c_2}$, but any kind of $g$ will minimalize it with $f=0$.

Comment: @Botond , The equation $c_2f(x,y)=0$ comes from optimizing $g(x,y$, right? If so, I think I do not need that, because g(x,y) is known. I realized that this is unclear in the question. I'll edit it.

Comment: Yes, I've got it from that. And what do we know about $c_1$, $c_2$, $c_3$,$C_1$ and $g(x,y)$? Also, aren't there any $\partial_x f$ or $\partial_y f$ in the Lagrangian?

Comment: @Botond , we know everything about the constants ang $g$, there are not derivatives in the lagrangian (I just edited for clarification)

Comment: What I mean is that isn't any restriction on them? For example, $\frac{C_1}{c_1}$ can only be negative, or something like that?

Comment: @Botond, the constants are all positive

Comment: +1. This is a very well-written question, and the user put a lot of effort into it to make it readable.

Comment: @user1271772 Thank you